# Get last line Column on MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have 1 column name: `PersonID` it contain name ex john doe

```
Table name: Person
Column name: PersonID

line1: John Doe
line2: Doe john
```

now to extract the last line?

this code return number of total line but not text of line

```
SELECT "PersonID", COUNT(*) FROM "Person";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order descending, then use the limit to return the last row -- now in the first position!

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
ORDER BY PersonId DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: yes it work thanks so much this.. correct query: SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY PersonId DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Ah yes, I've been doing too much Linq and have forgotten SQL :) Glad you got it working.

Comment: sorry not work like this: http://postimage.org/image/7h3qslw4x/full/ last line is sdsd and it return ssssss

Comment: Then you have to think about what "last line" means to the database. Is it the last one inserted? It would be more common to make the id column an autonumbered integer. If you do that, then the above pattern will work. I'd suggest doing that. Alternatively add a timestamp column and order on that. You might also be able to get the last updated row somehow. I know you can do that in SQL Server stored procedures.

Comment: ok thanks.. i have added a ID column autoincrement and it work but return ex 1johndoe or 4sdsd how to remove the id number?

Comment: Yeahhh add a characters | before line ex: |john doe and use this 
string output = row.Substring(row.IndexOf('|') + 1); in this mode the text before | will delete and return only line.. thanks to all!

Comment: @Federal09, personally I'd make the `id` column an integer data type, not a string. Then if you need to get at the user's name, put it into another column such as `user_name`. Then you don't have to do funny string manipulation like that. Most databases I've seen use different columns for this kind of thing, and I'd encourage you to do so too.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Person order by PERSONID DESC Limit 0,1
```